# Does lockscreen widget still supports in compatibility mode on Android 5 and above?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, app-widgets, lock-screen-widgets

As per the documentation here:

1. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets
2. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#lockscreen-widget-support-removed

Google has removed support of lock screen widget from Android 5.0 and above then how this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.medicalid.free) is still showing widget on lockscreen?

Phone is running on Android 8.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is a widget and not just a notification of the "Medical ID" app?

Comment: I don't think this behaviour can be achieved by notification. It is showing in widgets for home screen and the same thing is showing in lock screen also. It can be customised to floatable icon, or floatable window and it is draggable to anywhere in the screen. It shows everytime screen gets locked and removes when unlock the device. The app is free, you can try and check.

Comment: The app seems to rely on accessibility service to display that widget like object on the lock screen. If you disable the service you don't get to see that object on the lock screen at all. I, however, have failed to find how the app is using that service to show that object without necessarily relying on overlay permission.